# How Handle 1000 google map api calls in single request

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, concurrency, passenger

```
result = GoogleMapsAPI::DistanceMatrix.calculate([origins], [destinations],
         options = {})
```

Need to call the above function 1000 time to generate a report. How to improve the performance of the server in the above situation. We are using `nginx` and `passenger` with `rails 4.0`

Comment: Is it possible to use background jobs in your case?